# Convert path into its GUID form

Tags: c#, guid, filepath

I need to convert path (for example `C:\`) into that volume's GUID form (for example `\\\?\Volume{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}\`).

Is there any function in C# that does something like this?

Comment: `Path.Combine(@"C:\", "Volume{" + Guid.NewGuid() + "}");` ???

Comment: Well, Guid.NewGuid creates new guid, doesn't it? I need to get volumes guid, such as "mountvol.exe" in cmd.

Comment: His question is clear, he's just assuming domain knowledge. He's asking how to get the volume GUID path of a mount point.

Comment: For those wondering about their personal volume guids; execute `mountvol C:\ /L` from a command prompt.

Comment: Each volume (C:\, D:\ etc.) has it's own GUID (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365248(v=vs.85).aspx). I need to get this GUID having only volume path (for example "C:\")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to P/Invoke `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint`:

```
static string GetVolumeGuidPath(string mountPoint)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);
    GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(mountPoint, sb, 50);
    return sb.ToString();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(
    string lpszVolumeMountPoint,
    [Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName,
    int cchBufferLength);
```